# Encoding problem on Careers ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising, encoding

There's an encoding problem on the Careers ads.    This should be '*George Patterson Y&R*'.

HTMLEncode() where it shouldn't be?

[image: That ain't no ampersand]

**Update #1**
16th April 2012 - Still happening.  Here's another example:

[image: More encoding problems]

Comment: Looks like a case of double encoding. Also, [JEPG for screenshots](http://i.imgur.com/eBnYD.jpg)?

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ Don't like the .jpg?  No problem, one .tif coming up! ; )

Comment: Better yet, [double double-encoding](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pD7ke.png)!