# Something&#39;s wrong with the inbox message escaping

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, global-inbox

Here's a sample of my StackExchange Inbox this morning:

[image]

[image]

The apostrophe ' is being improperly/unnecessarily escaped to `&#39;` in the inbox.

It's also doing it to double quotes:

[image]

As well as ampersands:

[image]

---

<sub><sup>No the title isn't bugged I was just making a joke</sup></sub>

Comment: Expect to revert a lot of helpful edits to your title. In fact, I jumped in here specifically to fix it. Fortunately, I actually _read_ your question.

Comment: Been seeing this today as well. I'd already posted a similar bug _roots around_

Comment: Aah http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/multicollider-breaking-html-entities Not a dupe, though

Comment: Oh. I've been meaning to submit this for a while... stupid short-term memory loss.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this too!

Comment: +2 for making me think. -1 for doing it in the morning!

Comment: It appears you are channeling the spirit of [Tim Stone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone).  See [You got your double encoded space in my tooltip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94051/you-got-your-double-encoded-space-in-my-tooltip).  Oh those SE devs, will they ever learn =P

Comment: Interesting that the "hot questions" tab shows them correctly but the inbox is double-escaped.

Comment: I also saw an `&amp;` in my inbox with a notification of some messages for me in the E&R Moderator Chatroom, so it's not just this character...

Comment: @KevinVermeer that's odd, I see normal ampersands in my inbox, not in the title of chat rooms though

Comment: @BenBrocka - I'll do some "testing" & see if it's working now.  <-- What do you see there?

Comment: @KevinVermeer it's fixed now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This only relates to inbox items from chat, but yes: it was a bit dodgy for about 8 hours. This was noticed and fixed about 12 hours ago, so you should be fine now. It was entirely my fault; was trying to tidy up how markdown appeared, but it got a bit over-excited and over-encoded things. Always better than the alternative, of course.

Comment: Don't forget to fix the same problem in the career ads while you're at it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126603/encoding-problem-on-careers-ads

Answer (score 3):

It's also happening in the inbox at `http://stackexchange.com/users/[User ID]?tab=inbox`.

There, I was able to go back a couple days and find that older messages do not suffer from this problem:

[image]

The double quotes on *"A" sizes* were shown correctly on 05/07 at 14:24, but *Teachers&#39; Lounge* was messed up on 05/07 at 18:23, less than 4 hours later.

Hopefully that helps you narrow down to the commit that broke the encoding.