# Global Inbox cuts preview mid &ndas HTML &ndas entity

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

If a HTML entity is across the limit of the preview, it is truncated, leaving things looking like this;

[image]

Comment: Related: [Something&#39;s wrong with the inbox message escaping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131807/166936) but apparently not the same issue. I've seen this as well.

Comment: This bug still occurs. I had it occur this week with https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46368649#46368649 and https://i.stack.imgur.com/0efo2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll be smarter about choosing where to truncate inbox item summaries.

This will only apply going forward, as items already in the inbox have already been summarized for display.

Comment: Seems like this bug is still around, I've just had an inbox preview ending with `split("\n&quo...`.