# Inbox chops messages in the middle of an HTML character reference

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, html-entities, truncation

The messages in the inbox get chopped if they too long, and the chop can occur in the middle of an HTML character reference as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: brutally chopped comment]

The character being chopped is `[` and it appears inside a code snippet, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: [Global Inbox cuts preview mid &ndas HTML &ndas entity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/global-inbox-cuts-preview-mid-ndas-html-ndas-entity) - regression.

Comment: For me, an [apostrophe shows up as a box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdgDE.png). See the [original chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64129106#64129106).