# Notifications with a HTML encoded entity render improperly if a truncation occurs in the middle of the entity

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, html-entities

I received the below notification yesterday:

[image: Notification from a chatroom message where the truncation point falls right in the middle of a HTML-encoded entity]

The chat message itself can be found at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46368649#46368649:

> iunno I'm just saying that it's not out of the question for it to just be a "hey I took care of a thing" situation

What seems to happen here is that the truncation point falls right in the middle of a HTML-encoded entity, which then doesn't render properly.

While creating this bug report, I have found a number of earlier bug reports dealing with the same issue: [Global Inbox cuts preview mid &ndas HTML &ndas entity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/global-inbox-cuts-preview-mid-ndas-html-ndas-entity), [Inbox chops messages in the middle of an HTML character reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213019/inbox-chops-messages-in-the-middle-of-an-html-character-reference) which leads me to believe there is some sort of regression during the implementation of the new header.