# Inbox not rendering HTML entities when they end a message-preview in the Inbox

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, html-entities, regression

My inbox decided to truncate the message preview partway through the HTML entity for a single quote in the word "doesn't". This is... odd. Can it be changed to extend the preview to go all the way to the end of the word?

I got an inbox message as I was pinged in chat

[image]

---

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/global-inbox-cuts-preview-mid-ndas-html-ndas-entity). While it is the same thing, it is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so I'm assuming this is a regression and so I'm reporting this

Comment: Looks like case of bug that was never fixed despite the developer's best efforts, who later failed to reply to comments saying it's not fixed. That's, sadly,  not rare in SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notifications with a HTML encoded entity render improperly if a truncation occurs in the middle of the entity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314620/notifications-with-a-html-encoded-entity-render-improperly-if-a-truncation-occur). Regression all the way back to 2013.