# Post body elision doesn’t handle HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, html-entities

I am seeing this on the [questions page of Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions) right now:

[image: "Block&...]

The question description is truncated right in the middle of the `&quot;` HTML entity. The result is the string `"Block&...`, which seems like a bug.

Expected result: `"Block"...`

Actual result: `"Block&...`

I expect this behavior is universal across all SE sites.

Comment: This is similar to [Inbox chops messages in the middle of an HTML character reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213019).

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but should be higher priority as the bug here affect way more people.

Comment: This is [still happening](//i.stack.imgur.com/mHBfR.png), e.g. with [input autocomplete is not working for any input](//stackoverflow.com/q/68138958/4642212).