# There&#39;s an encoded HTML entity in the tooltips for flag decline messages

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, tooltips, character-escaping

Looking at the *Declined* tooltip in the flagging history of a post gives me this nice message:

[image]

Looks like someone forgot to decode the entities there.

Comment: There#&39;s an encoded HTML entity in your title

Comment: @chuex - the irony of that is either intentional or accidental by the OP. The fact that we aren't sure which is also ironic. Hmmm.... meta-irony on the meta site.

Comment: Is this mod only tool? Can't find such a thing anywhere.

Comment: ...must...not...fix...title...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - yes, it is.

Comment: It&#39;s not the first time this has happened - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131807/something39s-wrong-with-the-inbox-message-escaping