# HTML encoding strikes again (but with a twist) - Chat messages inbox notifications aren&#39;t looking good

Tags: bug, global-inbox, encoding

I just noticed this in my inbox:

> [image]

Same appears in the global inbox of the network profile.

This looks like  [this other bug that was reported and fixed over four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131807/something39s-wrong-with-the-inbox-message-escaping), with the difference that it happens only if the word containing the special character is the last when truncating the message.

Can it please be fixed? Since it's hard to know which word will be the last, it's hard to reproduce hence not sure if it affects only chat notifications or other types of notifications as well.

Comment: @zaq I'm now waiting for a new notification to be created.

Comment: The Unicode fails to work properly, and the system cusses.

Comment: Still not fixed!

Comment: @Rahul2001 like thousands of other non-critical bugs, yep.

Comment: @Glorfindel pretty sure I checked and it affects only chat messages notifications.

Comment: I noticed today that there are four or five open bug reports about the same issue. It might be worth making a 'canonical' bug report then?

Comment: @Glorfindel can you ev'en reproduce &#39 this bug?

Comment: @Glorfindel most likely comment notifications are no longer causing any trouble? ^ (So we need to find what bugs are still open and ask mods to put completed tags on those that are fixed.)