# Rendering problem with targeted job (ie, "Looking for a job?") block

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising

The new [targeted job ad](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) block shows HTML entities rather than their evaluated content for some ads:

[image]

It seems the problem is isolated to `Dubai, United Arab Emirates`:

[image]

Comment: I was going to put this on meta.stackexchange; but I thought as the job ads are only for SO, it was not appropriate here.

Comment: MSE is the place for Careers related issues, so it fits here better.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126603/encoding-problem-on-careers-ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. Our function that abbreviates long location strings was also html encoding them, which ended up causing double encoding issues.

Thanks for your report <3

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is resolved:

[image]